# How to parse multiline ELK based on Timestamp

Tags: logging, elastic-stack, filebeat

My logs are

```
2017-07-04 10:19:52,896 - [INFO] - from application in ForkJoinPool-3-worker-1

Resolving database...

2017-07-04 10:19:52,897 - [INFO] - from application in ForkJoinPool-3-worker-1

Resolving database...

2017-07-04 10:19:52,897 - [DEBUG] - from application in ForkJoinPool-3-worker-1

Json Body : {"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]},"aggregations":{"fp":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}}}

2017-07-04 10:19:52,898 - [DEBUG] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-53

Successfully updated the transaction.

2017-07-04 10:19:52,899 - [INFO] - from application in ForkJoinPool-3-worker-1

Resolving database...

2017-07-04 10:19:52,901 - [DEBUG] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-54

Successfully updated the transaction.
```

I want to group all logs between two timestamp together match them with 
GREEDYDATA.
I am using filebeat with ELK

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it via following configuration

-

```
  paths: 
    - /var/www/aspserver/logs/application.log
  document_type: asp
  input_type: log
  multiline:
    pattern: '^[0-9]'
    negate: true
    match: after
```

Matchin all line after a line starting with number and merging them together.

```
logstash filter : 
filter {
  if [type] == "asp" {
    grok {
      patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/patterns"
      match => { "message" => "%{JAVASTACKTRACEPART}" }
    }
  }
}
```

Gobble up all the logs